# Preview and final formatting are not consistent

Tags: discussion, markdown, markdown-preview

There are quite a few questions here about formatting, but I could not find anything to answer my problem.

I've been [answering](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/2202/1009) a question on Linguistic site, and the question was about word inflections. Naturally, I was trying to highlight suffixes of inflected words.

I typed `aaa**bbb**`, expecting the output to be like this aaa**bbb**, and it worked fine in preview.

When I submitted the answer, it apparently looked like this: aaa**bbb**

Well, then I decided italic would be fine as well and edited my answer like this: `aaa*bbb*`, expecting to get aaa*bbb*. Again, it looked nice in preview, but after submission it was aaa*bbb*.

I've ended up with explicit HTML tags (as well as writing very this question:)), but still, is there any simpler way to get **formatting inside the words**? It works fine for preview, so I guess they can just be synchronized.

**UPD**: Even more, `aaa***bbb***` renders as aaa***bbb***, so it is certainly possible to make it bold.

Comment: `aaa**bbb**` renders the same in both the preview and the post?

Comment: @Matt: It did not work for me, at least on Linguistics site. I'm asking here because I feel it affects the entire SO engine. If this setting is individual per site, maybe I have to move my question to Linguistics Meta.